# U disagree with me and I say "U always do the same", actually me doing the same!

Tags: fallacies

Sometimes people are talking to you, then you disagree with them, then they will accuse you of "always disagreeing and/or not compliant". But in fact they are doing the same thing that they are accusing - Disagreement. What fallacy or term does it fall under?

Example:
Person A- The president is an honest guy

Person B- I dont agree

Person A- Yea, its not new, u never agree with me.

here person A is doing the same thing.

Comment: You could say that this is hypocritical, but hypocrisy is not a fallacy. That they are doing the same does not imply that you are not doing it, so there is no fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a few fallacies/cognitive biases come to mind:

1. Hasty/Sweeping generalization: You may not be *always* disagreeing with someone. The *sample* from which the generalization is made is either *too small* or *biased*
2. Confirmation bias/cherry picking: Noticing only those times when there's a disagreement and ignoring all the other times when there's agreement
3. Red Herring: The issue is, in the example given, the president's character and shifting the focus away from that to agreement-disagreement is an illicit move
4. Ignoratio elenchi (missing the point): In the given example, one interlocutor is making a point about the president, but the other thinks its about agreement-disagreement

Comment: Good answer.  Bad argumentation need not have a *single* fault